# java.lang.NullPointerException: Android Attempt to invoke virtual method error

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

My android webview fragment app is getting crashed, after i have added a button to go from one fragment to another, the error on the console is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ahmed.stories, PID: 11846
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ahmed.stories.MainActivity.setUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.ahmed.stories.Saying$3.onPageStarted(Saying.java:127)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:517)
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:144)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

It says the problem is with line 127 which is with `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setUrl(url);` but i can't find anything wrong with it, am ew to android and trying to learn, may be you guys can help.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.ahmed.stories;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    TextView home_tv, stories, bookmarks, drafts, fakecheck, lost, leaving;
    CardView lyt_top_bar;
    View toolbar_line;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;

    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Home home = new Home();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, home, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_search:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Search search = new Search();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, search, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_edit:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Edit edit = new Edit();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, edit, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_message:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Notification notification = new Notification();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, notification, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;


                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Profile profile = new Profile();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, profile, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
         navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navigation));

        bookmarks = findViewById(R.id.bookmarks);
        stories = findViewById(R.id.stories);
        home_tv = findViewById(R.id.home_tv);
        lyt_top_bar = findViewById(R.id.lyt_top_bar);
        toolbar_line = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_line);

        stories.setOnClickListener(this);
        home_tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        bookmarks.setOnClickListener(this);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Home home = new Home();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, home, "Home");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main3, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            shareTextUrl();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        showSystemUI();
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Profile profile = new Profile();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, profile, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Edit edit = new Edit();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, edit, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Drafts drafts = new Drafts();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, drafts, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fakecheck fakecheck = new Fakecheck();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fakecheck, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_lost) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Lost lost = new Lost();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, lost, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Leaving leaving = new Leaving();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, leaving, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {

        lyt_top_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar_line.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void showSystemUI() {
        lyt_top_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbar_line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
//        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
//                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
//        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showSystemUI();
        if (v == home_tv) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Saying saying = new Saying();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, saying, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            saying.hideProgress();
            hideSystemUI();
        }

        if (v == bookmarks) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Bookmarks bookmarks = new Bookmarks();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, bookmarks, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == drafts) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Drafts drafts = new Drafts();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, drafts, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == fakecheck) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fakecheck fakecheck = new Fakecheck();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fakecheck, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == lost) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Lost lost = new Lost();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, lost, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == leaving) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Leaving leaving = new Leaving();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, leaving, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == stories) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Trending trending = new Trending();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, trending, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
    String urlOpen="";
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.urlOpen = url;
    }
    public void shareTextUrl(){
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
        // what to do with it.
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlOpen);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "We Only share with the people we care!"));
    }
    public void goToHome(){
        showSystemUI();
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Home home = new Home();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, home, "Home");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**Saying Fragment**

```
package com.ahmed.stories;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by ahmed on 21/4/18.
 */

public class Saying extends BaseFragment {

    private String postUrl = "https://wewritesay.herokuapp.com";
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView home_web;
    ImageButton btn_home;
    private float m_downX;

    //
    public Saying() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgress() {
        if (progressBar != null)
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //    https://my-medium-clone.herokuapp.com/top-stories
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saying, container, false);
        home_web = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_web);
        btn_home = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
        btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).goToHome();
            }
        });
        WebSettings settings = home_web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        home_web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        home_web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSavePassword(true);
        settings.setSaveFormData(true);
        settings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
//        home_web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        home_web.loadUrl(postUrl);
        home_web.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && home_web.canGoBack()) {
                    home_web.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        initWebView();
//        home_web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        return view;
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        Context context;

        public MyWebChromeClient(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }


    }

    private void initWebView() {
        home_web.setWebChromeClient(new Saying.MyWebChromeClient(getActivity()));
        home_web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setUrl(url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                home_web.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
        home_web.clearCache(true);
        home_web.clearHistory();
        home_web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        home_web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        home_web.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    //Multi touch detected
                    return true;
                }

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        // save the x
                        m_downX = event.getX();
                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        // set x so that it doesn't move
                        event.setLocation(m_downX, event.getY());
                    }
                    break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: getActivity()==null.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}
```

and then to prevent leaks:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mContext = null;
}
```

Now to use MainActivity do:

```
((MainActivity)mContext).setUrl(url);
```

Comment: Hey @HaroldSer am really new to android, and trying to teach myself, i didn't understand what you did, can you please elaborate. It will be a big help Thanks.

Comment: onAttach() we are simply obtaining reference to the activity the fragment is attached to(which later we use to invoke the method setUrl(url).  Now, because we want to make sure there is not memory leak(the reference of the activity the fragment was attached to is still live after dettachment) we have to set the reference of the activity null on onDetach().  See fragment lifecycle.